# Flutter app should lock the screen if no activity from a user for 10 minutes

Tags: flutter, android-activity, locking

How can I lock my Flutter app if there is no activity from a user for 10 minutes? It means, if the user doesn't do anything for 10 minutes after his/her last activity (key stroke, scrolling, navigation, ...) then I should popup a lock screen asking the user to enter a PIN in order to unlock and continue. How can I do it?
I've already developed the lock screen but the real problem here is to detect the user's activities.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has a method for this
didChangeAppLifecycleState method
it can detect 4 types of state 1. detached 2.inactive 3.paused 4. resumed
You can google the method for more info.

Comment: I already use didChangeAppLifecycleState and states: paused, resumed when my app goes to the background and comes back from it. I think I need a listener for all user activities where I would track a time when they occur. Every next activity override the dateTime flag with DateTime.now(). Then I need a timer when I would check if the current date and time is more than 10 minutes after and open the lock screen. The biggest challenge here is to listen on all user activities. Hope this helps to explain what is expectation here.